# VSCode Jupyter Notebook - Restore Cache Version

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was creating a Jupyter Notebook using VSCode (v 1.48.0) running on Ubuntu 19.10. VSCode crashed and unfortunately I had not saved the notebook, and when I restarted it was empty.

I have been able to find what looks like a cached version of the notebook in ~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-python.python , in a file called 527ed533.ipynb. [Small sample of what the file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON8q0.png)

Reviewing the contents of the file, I can tell that this is the notebook I was working on, but the format looks a bit garbled,

When I try and open the file back up in VSCode it just recognises this as text. I have tried to open it on Jupyter server too and it also does not recognise this as a valid notebook.

I tried to do a bit of manual editing of the data, mainly to remove everything other than the "cells" but this was not successful.

Is there any way that I can get the notebook back from this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manual way:**

- Copy contents from your temp file.
- Run this script by placing the content here (in Chrome inspector's console).

```js
var fileContent = << paste it just like that >>;   // It's an object
console.log(unescape(fileContent.contents));
```

- Copy the contents that are logged in console.
- Create a new file with .ipynb, open and paste it here.

**Output:**

[image: output]

I did notice such files but in a different location, I use Mac.

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-python.python/4ae407c9.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

I also bumped into this problem. I recovered the source code by using this script

```
import json
with open('b1d10574.ipynb', 'r') as f1, open('example.py', 'w') as f2:
    data = json.loads(json.load(f1)['contents'])
    for cell in data['cells']:
         f2.write("# %%\n")
         for line in cell['source']:
             f2.write(line) 
         f2.write("\n")
```

[image]